# Files in folder missing when using docker compose up

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am building an ASP.NET Core Web API Project that serves a zip file via http. The Files that should be served are stored in a directory called `Releases` inside the project. I have used Visual Studio 2022s built in "Add > Container Orchestrator Support" feature to generate the docker-compose files, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2022). When starting the containers via Visual Studios run Button on the top, everything works fine. However, when starting the containers via `docker compose up`, the `Releases` directory at runtime does not contain any files, only other directories. What am I missing?

(relevant) file structure of my project:

```
MyApp/
├─ docker-compose.yml
├─ docker-compose.override.yml
├─ MyApp.sln
├─ MyApp/
│  ├─ MyApp.csproj
│  ├─ Program.cs
│  ├─ Dockerfile
│  ├─ Releases/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  releasemanager:
    container_name: app
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp
    build:  
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp/Dockerfile
```

MyApp.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <UserSecretsId>***</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the files are being copied to release folder when you do the publish cmd. try to run publish cmd locally and see the content of published folder. normally in such cases we forget to set the property of files to copy always to output folder in project file.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer completely. You are right, only some of the files in my Releases directory are copied into the bin/Debug folder upon publishing, which might be the problem. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: just include two more thing in your question 1. file name which should be copied to release folder and 2. content of your project file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the question and added my csproj file. I want everything inside my Releases folder to be copied (around 40 files of different filetypes).